# Jersey is unable to encode entity as JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jetty, jackson

I got several classes that are annotated with meta information:

```
@Metadata(id="Foo",number=3)
public class Foo {
  ...
}

@Metadata(id="Bar",number=11)
public class SomeBar {
  ...
}
```

Now I want to publish this meta information via Jersey, returning it as a JSON structure. To do so I created a resource:

```
...
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response list(){
    ...
    List<Object> result=new LinkedList<>();
    for each class in (classes annotated with @Metadata) { //pseudo
         Metadata md=annotatedclass.getAnnotation(Metadata.class);
         result.add(md);
    }
    return Response.ok(result).build();
}
```

A browser call to this method fails with HTTP 500 / Server Error - without any further info! No exceptions in debug log, no extended info on the error page.

What actually works is translating `Metadata` objects "by hand". Substituting `result.add(md)` with `ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); result.add(mapper.writeValueAsString(md));` works perfectly. I get all the metadata objects serialized as (JSON-)Strings.

So what is Jetty doing different in serializing my metadata annotations?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can get the exception that causes the server error.

Comment: As I said before, there is no exception in the debug console.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Without knowing the cause of the 500 error it is very hard to why it is happening.